# How to cache static content with a certain condition

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I am using Apache httpd to front end a few application servers (eg, WebSphere, JBoss etc). I am also using Apache to cache the static content like gif, jpg, css etc. This works fine for most applications.

However, for a few applications, some of the static content (which are images like gif, jpg) is generated on the fly on the back-end application server. Hence the above procedure fails to work for these applications.

Can I setup Apache httpd such that it serves static content if it finds it on Apache httpd but if a 404 is returned it passes the request to the back-end application server ?

Comment: "some of the static content is generated on the fly on the back-end application server" - this mean this content is not static and must be served by app server

Comment: The static content are image files like gif, jpg ; thus it is static content, not dynamic.

Comment: No, the static content is file which do not change over the time and exist already (no need to be generated every time). It can be not only image but also text, html and so on.